# load html instead of a div Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-models

javascript:

```
$('.openDiv').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),
            id: id,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/setting/save-reporter/',
        success: function () {
            $('#authorisedreporter').load('save_reporter.html');
        }
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="authorisedreporter" {% if not registerform.errors %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
   <form method="post" action="." id="reporter-form">
   {% csrf_token %}
      <table  width="100%">
         """"""""
      </table></form></div>
```

save_reporter.html

```
<form method="post" action="." id="{{ id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table  width="100%">
    """""""""
    </table></form>
```

I am using ajax with js,after successfull ajax call,the div is replaced by save_reporter.html.But i am getting 404 page not found error in console.If i am not using `$('#authorisedreporter').load('save_reporter.html');` ,i am getting the required output in console.While trying to show the output in template i did that and i am getting the error.Need help.

Comment: `action="."` doesn't do what you think, make it empty. The 404 is most likely because `"/setting/save-reporter/"` isn't a valid URL for the original AJAX post.

Comment: @AdamKG Previously i was getting the output in console,after making this change in js $('#authorisedreporter').load('save_reporter.html'); made 404 error.

Comment: @AdamKG I've no idea what you think the OP thinks `action="."` does, or what you think it does. However, it is the *right* thing to do, and `action=""` will do the *wrong* thing if for example the original URL does not end in a final slash.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so it is, not sure why I thought that, thanks & TIL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the jQuery `load` function to load templates from Django. Templates are not standalone HTML pages: as you already know from writing the other views, you need to write a URL and a view to render the template and return it.

What you should be doing is getting your `/setting/save-reporter/` view to return the rendered template, and insert that result in your div via `.html()`:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#authorisedreporter').html(response);
```